# basic authorization in .net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to move an mvc app to .net core 2 and one of the last things I need to migrate is basic authorization which affects two controller methods.  Everything I can find shows a user logging in and that's not what we're doing in this case.  These methods just take a json post so I just need to make sure the basic authorization header is there with a value matching our system.

In my mvc app I have this class.

```
public class APIAuthenticationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] != null && httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].Equals("Basic " + ApiCredentials.EncodedHeader);
    }
}
```

And the controller method like

```
[APIAuthenticationFilter]
public ActionResult DoSomething(){...}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the issue and your expectation in detail?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what else to say that the code and question don't cover.  I'm looking for a basic authorization header in the controller request that has a specific value.  In mvc, it was easy enough to implement that check by decorating the controller method with my custom authentication filter.  In .net core it doesn't work.  So how can I recreate something like this for .net core?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744561/how-to-do-simple-header-authorization-in-net-core-2-0) help?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!